# Yammer OAuth for Data Export

Tags: oauth, yammer

Sorry to sound like a noob, but I am trying to hack my way through creating a script (hopefully Powershell) that will automate data exports from Yammer Enterprise. Yammer's doc regarding this is clear enough and I shouldn't have any problem getting this to work once I have a method for authentication.

Unfortunately I am unable to wrap my head around exactly how to pass an OAuth access token in order to do this. I have been following this guide but can't quite understand what is going on in steps 2 and 3:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2013/10/05/using-the-yammer-api-in-a-net-client-application.aspx

Now I am definitely not a web developer so I have no experience with Oauth and REST in general. Does anyone know of a clearer method for doing this? Am I completely barking up the wrong tree? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't have time to write up an answer at this minute, but have you looked at https://developer.yammer.com/authentication/? You can perform the server-side flow using notepad and a web browser to get a token. You need to register an app in Yammer first as that provides the inputs such as client secret. Once you have the OAuth token you simply pass it as the Authorization header eg. Authorization: Bearer jsd903sdfnjksdsdfnjk

Comment: Ok. I was looking for a way to programmatically retrieve this auth token at runtime rather than storing it. I have gone through the server side flow and it looks like I have a good token. Thanks for your help!

Comment: So I used the process according to the Authentication document but am still unable to authenticate. I have an app set up with https://www.yammer.com as the redirect URL. I used the client ID and secret to obtain my own access token. However, any sort of web request that I use with the authorization header set to my access token results in a 401 unauthorized error. I feel like I'm getting closer but just don't understand the web stuff well enough to get this right.

Comment: So using www.yammer.com as the redirect uri and the target of a web request gets a response, but using www.yammer.com/api/v1/export does not and I continue to get an unauthorized error. Here is a snippet of my Powershell that is failing:                       $Web = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$Web.Headers.Add('Authorization', "1234567891234567891234") 
$Web.DownloadData("https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/export?since=2014-07-01T04:00:00+00:00")

Comment: It seems now that this just doesn't work as described in the Authentication document. I tried using yammer's example using wget and explicitly adding my access token to the header which alway results in a 401 response. I am now awaiting approval for the Yammer developer's network in order to ask about this there. Thanks for your help!

Comment: can you post the actual script you are running?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't get to this over the weekend. I am just using the wget example from the documentation:wget.exe" -o "c:\dataexport" -t 1 --header "Authorization: Bearer Wu9HgAjKPR9uLaoTBn9dnr" "https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/export" --ca-certificate cacert.pem